# Observe NSLog messages in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, nslog

I'm debugging a 3rd party SDK which puts lot of useful information into the console.

I used to display some messages in tooltips (for our tester), which I'm receiving from SDK delegate.

But delegate methods don't include many details and sometimes it turns helpless, otherwise console includes much more helpful information (especially if the SDK's log level is set to `DEBUG_ALL` or something like that).

**So, my question - is it possible to observe `NSLog` messages and to be notified in some way when they are printed to console? Of course I would like to have string message as a parameter?**

I would like to display it on device/simulator screen, so that the tester doesn't have to run XCode or view the device's console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using [iConsole](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iConsole) for the same purpose. It's quite useful.

Comment: Does it allow you to view NSLog messages on device (not [iConsole ...]) ?

Comment: No, you'll have to redirect NSLog, using `frepoen(3)` to write the logs to another file and then modify iConsole.m to read and write the logs to that file as well, but the iConsole project provides you with a very nice way of presenting the logs and the modifications you'll have to make are very tiny.

Comment: I don't have access to SDK's source code, I can do nothing with NSLog inside it

Comment: You don't need to have access to the SDK's source code to redirect `NSLog`. `NSLog` writes it's output to `stderr`. You'll have to use `freopen` to redirect all `NSLog`s. example: `freopen("/path/to/console.log","a+",stderr);`

Answer (score 0):

What SDK? If the SDK supports CocoaLumberjack, then I suggest installing that, and configuring the loggers to do what you want -- even route somewhere else.

CocoaLumberjack gives you **a lot** of power and configurability when it comes to logging.

Comment: F.e some advertising SDKS like AdMob, Mopub etc

Answer (score 0):

If your SDK uses `NSLog` to print the details in the console, then you can use macros to redefine the `NSLog`.

```
    #define NSLog(FORMAT, ...) ShowLogInAlert(FORMAT);


   void ShowLogInAlert(NSString *format, ...){
    //show the log in the alert here.

    va_list ap;
    va_start (ap, format);
    format = [format stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",format] arguments:ap];
//    NSLog(@"%@", msg);
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:msg message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    va_end (ap);

}
```

Comment: it's not MINE SDK, I can't change it. I need kind of global overriding

Comment: I put it to "main" and added breakpoint there, but it doesn't work

Comment: I have updated my answer. Try now. It should be working.

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work, compiler doesn't go to that method. I use "Debug" scheme and 'm testing on simulator. Maybe I'm doing smth wrong?

Comment: It should be working, maybe u r doing smth different. I use this method to log the messages to a file.